# My c language code doesn't run in VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSYH0.jpg)

I done everything that requires downloaded wingw gcc compiler and set the path in environment variable section but still doesn't run. Help pls

I tried again to download vs code and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. From the [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow): [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: and… I mean. Come on. Your computer has a "screenshot" functionality. Even if you didn't know that, taking a photo with flash on so that it's hard to read — at least *try* to put sensible effort into asking a question that can be answered based on the material you provide.

Answer (score 3):

You can see it runs the command `gcc c practice.c` and then complains that there are no such files `c` and `practice.c`. This is because you need to quote the filename if it contains spaces to prevent it from being split into two different file arguments. So the correct command would be:

```
gcc "c practice.c" -o "c practice"
```

Assuming you didn't write this command yourself and let some vscode extension compile it, it may be a bug in the extension. Easiest workaround is to rename the file without spaces: `c_practice.c`

Comment: Yeah, putting spaces in source file names is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

i also face the same problem so you follow some steps
1.Go to my computer and click search option in there, 2.In the search box type "Mingw"
3.you see the folder called "Mingw" 4.delete that folder and reinstall from browser;

Comment: Please don't delete folders containing installed software. That's terrible advice - the paths that mingw set still linger on the system, the start menu entries, file associations, handlers... It installed are now dangling.